# mySQL query not returning correct results!

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

This query that I have is returning therapists whose 'therapistTable.activated' is equal to false as well as those set to true! so it's basically selecting all of the db, any advice would be appreciated!

```
`           $query = "SELECT
                 therapistTable.*
                 FROM
                 therapistTable
                 WHERE
                 therapistTable.activated = 'true'
                 ORDER BY 
                 therapistTable.distance
                 ";              
`
```

Comment: Pete: In your question, please provide the output of the following `SHOW CREATE TABLE therapistTable`

Comment: im sorry but theres some sensitive info in it

Comment: show create table, wont show any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the column type of the column `activated`, and what are some sample values from the table?

Is it perhaps a BOOL, or some other integer value?  'true' is a string - TRUE is an integer.

If therapistTable.activated is a BOOL, you will want to compare it to TRUE instead of a string.

Comment: its actually a varchar with a string, but i'll change it to a boolean and try that

Comment: Oh hey, don't go doing that on a whim - nothing wrong with storing string values.

What are some sample values from the table?

Comment: k it didn't work, i turned it back to a varchar i use navicat to set the value of therapistTable.activated to true or false no quotes or anything just that,

Comment: interestingly when i run the same query through navicat it worked properly

Comment: i got it i apologize turns out that wasnt the query being sent, the query runs perfectly well like

`           $query = "SELECT
                 therapistTable.*
                 FROM
                 therapistTable
                 WHERE
                 therapistTable.activated = 'true'
                 ORDER BY 
                 therapistTable.distance
                 ";              
`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a boolean type, you should be using `TRUE` and not`'true'`. I don't know how that would cause your problem though..

Just to explain: `TRUE` is an integer (equal to 1), but `'true'` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

`$query = "SELECT
                 therapistTable.*
                 FROM
                 therapistTable
                 WHERE
                 therapistTable.activated = 'true'
                 ORDER BY 
                 therapistTable.distance
                 ";`

is correct